# Capybara::ElementNotFound on all specs only on Travis

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, selenium, rspec, capybara

I'm using selenium, capybara with rspec for testing, i noticed all tests pass locally, but on travis all tests fail with this error on each spec.

```
Capybara::ElementNotFound:
```

I'm not sure what is wrong here, here is the specs runner on .travis.yml

```
script:
- xvfb-run bundle exec rspec spec/features/*.rb
```

for spec_helper.rb here is my config:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.treat_symbols_as_metadata_keys_with_true_values = true
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = false
  config.infer_base_class_for_anonymous_controllers = false1
  config.filter_run_excluding :broken => true
  config.render_views

Capybara.default_driver = :selenium
Capybara.default_selector= :css
Capybara.run_server = true
Capybara.default_wait_time = 30
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well I found the reason of the issue and the solution.

**Reason**: We use responsive design, and apparently travis uses a small window size which turned on the mobile design and that is why it couldn't find the elements.

**Solution**:

```
script:
- xvfb-run --server-args="-screen 0 1024x768x24" bundle exec rspec spec/features/*.rb
```

You basically set windows size to a larger size.