# Specs pass locally, but fail for Travis CI

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, capybara, travis-ci

I wrote some feature specs to test logging in through my rails app, and the specs all pass locally, but they fail when Travis CI runs them. Here is an example:

```
1) User Registration User signs up with valid credentials
     Failure/Error: fill_in 'Username', with: 'dannnnneh'
     Capybara::ElementNotFound:
       Unable to find field "Username"
     # ./spec/features/registrations_controller_spec.rb:8:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

I read on the [common build problems for Travis CI](http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/common-build-problems/#Capybara%3A-I%E2%80%99m-getting-errors-about-elements-not-being-found) to use `Capybara.default_wait_time = 15`; however, I either put that in the wrong place, or it doesn't work.

Example spec:

```
scenario 'User signs up with valid credentials' do
    Capybara.default_wait_time = 15
    visit '/users/sign_up'
    fill_in 'Username', with: 'dannnnneh'
    ...
```

EDIT:

I have also tried putting `Capybara.default_wait_time = 15` in `rails_helper.rb`, `spec_helper.rb`, `spec/support/capybara.rb`.

I also added the following to `.travis.yml` because of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20713471/capybaraelementnotfound-on-all-specs-only-on-travis?rq=1) SO question.

```
script:
    - xvfb-run bundle exec rspec spec/features/*.rb
```

However, that did not work either.

Does anyone know what the probelm might be or how to fix it?

EDIT:

Here is my `spec_helper.rb`:

```
require 'simplecov'
SimpleCov.start


require 'capybara'
require 'capybara/poltergeist'

Capybara.javascript_driver = :poltergeist
Capybara.register_driver :poltergeist do |app|
  Capybara::Poltergeist::Driver.new(app, timeout: 15)
end

RSpec.configure do |config|

  config.expect_with :rspec do |expectations|
    expectations.include_chain_clauses_in_custom_matcher_descriptions = true
  end

  config.mock_with :rspec do |mocks|
    mocks.verify_partial_doubles = true
  end

end
```

Comment: What driver are you using? Is there any javascript running on that page that might make the login box appear?

Comment: @DickieBoy I'm not using a driver, do I need one?

Comment: I believe I have set it up to use Poltergeist, but still no luck.

Comment: Are you doing a `bundle install` in your test script on travis?

Comment: Everything bundle installs automatically when travis runs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why travis CI was failing was because of an issue with `require_tree` in `application.js`. If the directory that `require_tree` is referencing is empty, then everything breaks. There are three solutions that I found.

1) Add a `.keep` file to the proper directory

2) Remove the `require_tree` statement and whatever is using it

3) Remove whatever is using the `require_tree` statement.

In my case, it was turbo-links that was causing the issue. I plan on implementing a front-end framework, so I removed the reference to turbo-links in `application.html.slim`

Travis CI only spit out this error when I switched from slim to erb, and `puts page.html` in one of my tests, so it was hard to track down.

Answer (score 2):

Can you post your spec_helper ? Also, the official documentation suggests another way to configure xvfb, have you checked http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/gui-and-headless-browsers/ ?

Comment: I posted my spec helper

Comment: Usually, I start my capybara tests with "xvfb-run -a". Can you try that ?

Comment: Thank you jiop for your help! I have posted the correct solution.

Comment: The author didn't mention that he needs GUI, therefore a suggestion to put configure `xvfb` makes no sense. It's not needed when headless browser is used.

Answer (score 2):

You have some problem or other, but no debug output, so it's hard to tell what's wrong. I would eliminate the issues one by one by altering your tests to give you that output. You could have one of the following (or something else):

- You may not be on the correct page because the navigation has failed
- You may not have anything on the page except an error message
- You may have something else on the page which is covering up the username field

Try adding a step that validates the page you are on:

```
expect(page).to have_current_path('/users/sign_up')
```

Or try adding a step that prints out the HTML for the page.

```
puts page.html
```

or if not...

```
fail page.html
```

You should find something of use to tell you why you cannot see the input you want to fill in.

Comment: I added `expect(current_path).to eq '/users/sign_up'` and that didn't trigger an error. However, when I `puts page.html` it looks like it isn't rendering the partials because it shows `= render "layouts/shared/side_bar"`, `= render "layouts/shared/header"`, `= render "layouts/shared/body"` Do you think the problem could be that I am using slim?

Comment: This helped me find the solution, so I have awarded you the bounty.

Comment: Don't `use expect(current_path)...` or your tests will fail randomply. Always use `expect(page).to have_current_path('/users/sign_up')` to give the browser/werbserver the wait time to do their work.

Answer (score 2):

Check whether TrevisCI can create test DB. 
For working with Travis CI, I had to create `public test DB` which TravisCI can use...

Comment: I don't believe that is the problem because only the feature specs fail where I actually visit the web page.

Comment: When I moved test DB into Amazon RDS, my RSpec on TravisCI began working propertly...